# How to pass data from fragment to fragment using multiple buttons?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I have two fragments,Fragment-1 and Fragment-2,in my Fragment-1 i have three buttons,in every button's listener i am sending data using bundle,and trying to get in Fragment-2 ,but app got crash and getting nullpointer exception

Fragment-1

```
 rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    All_Products tf = new All_Products();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("catagory_name", "All");

                    tf.setArguments(bundle);
                    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.container_body, tf);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });

            rl1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    All_Products tf = new All_Products();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


                    bundle.putString("jorel", proidslug1);


                    tf.setArguments(bundle);
                    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.container_body, tf);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();

                }
            });
            rl2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    All_Products tf = new All_Products();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("bestseller", proidslug2);
                    tf.setArguments(bundle);
                    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.container_body, tf);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();

                }
            });
```

Fragment-2

```
Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
        cname=bundle.getString("catagory_name");
        System.out.println("all >>>>>" + cname);

        Bundle b1=this.getArguments();
        jorlenm=b1.getString("jorel");
        System.out.println("jorel>>>>>" + jorlenm);


     if(cname.equals(bundle.getString("catagory_name")))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),cname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

           else if(jorlenm.equals(bundle.getString("jorel")))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jorlenm,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
```

Comment: Please add the logcat too.

Comment: What are `cname` and `jorlenm` in `Fragment2` ??

Comment: @Boss see edited question

Comment: If you clicked second button `bundle.getString("catagory_name");` this will be null.

Comment: so what is the solution for that?

Comment: @Johnson see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you clicked `rl1` button then the data passed to the bundle is with a key `jorel`.

Then the value in bundle with the key `category_name` will be `null`. Then by checking with a null value you may get an exception.

So you have to check if it is `null` or not.

Try this

```
    String cname = bundle.getString("catagory_name");
    String jorelnm = bundle.getString("jorel");
    String bestseller = bundle.getString("bestseller");

    if (cname != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (jorlenm != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jorlenm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } //..
```

Answer (score 1):

As @boss Suggested you need to have null checker when the 3 buttons are sending mutual exclusive data.

```
    Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
    cname=bundle.getString("catagory_name");
    jorlenm=bundle.getString("jorel");

 if(cname != null)
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),cname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } 

       else if(jorlenm != null)
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jorlenm,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```